# Giving each set its own data path in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a graph in ssrs. the graph displays data from various different sets in a single data path. now I want to plot each set in a different data path when i select multiple sets using a checkbox.
I added the 'set id' in series groups but am not getting different data paths corresponding to their sets..
any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by 'data path'?

Comment: the line which contains the plotting of values

Comment: When you add your set id what you see on your chart? no change? are you certain that there are different values in this field?

Comment: yeah,there are different values for set id. but no change in graph.

Comment: Can you post a portion of the dataset you are using? and indicate which fields are being used where?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand.Data source of my data set is a stored procedure. Should I post that or the fields in my data set and their corresponding field source....

Comment: the fields in your dataset, a sample of the data in the dataset (say 12 rows of example data), and how those field are set up in your report

Comment: please check my question once again, i have edited it with these details.@Nick.McDermaid

Answer (score 1):

The values are grouped using the Series Groups. Do you have your chart data grouped by SetID?

[image]